# Point group of cis- and trans-decalin

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, symmetry

What is the point group of of *cis*- and *trans*-decalin?

[image]

I watched a video saying that it is $C_\mathrm{2h}$ for *cis*-isomer, but my friend says it is $D_\mathrm{2h}.$ I'm so confused.

Comment: D2h should contain quite a few mirror planes. Where are they?

Comment: Please edit to add a link to the video (link to your friend is not necessary).

Comment: This video gets it right: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GERJoub3LVo

Answer (score 3):

**cis-Decalin**

Here is a view of cis-decalin with the bridging C-C bond in the plane of the paper:

[image]

(It was made using the Jmol software, e.g. at https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jsmol/simple.htm using the "Load by name" button and entering "cis-decalin".) At https://www.chemtube3d.com/stdecalinflips/, you can see that this can flip into the mirror image (much like a cylcohexane chair flip).

> What is the point group of of cis-decalin?

I see a two-fold axis (perpendicular to the paper). I don't see a center of inversion or any mirror planes; the molecule looks chiral (the flip mentioned above changes it to its mirror image). So maybe C2?

**trans-Decalin**

Here is a view of trans-decalin with 5 carbons closer to us and 5 further away from us:

[image]

I see a center of inversion, a mirror plane (left:right swap), and a two-fold horizontally in the plane of view. I guess that's C2h.

Comment: Related: [Does trans-decalin really have a plane of symmetry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/60830/4945) *Trigger warning:* You might be watching the gif forever...

Comment: I have run some conformational checks on the structures. The maximum point group for *cis*-decalin is as you propose C2. For *trans*-decalin, we do indeed find C2h as already stated. There are other (higher-energy) conformations with twist-boat rings in their conformations, which (mostly) would be of C1 symmetry.